# Spninx in indian slang accuracy is poor

Tags: java, cmusphinx

I'm using Speech recognition to recognise all th words !st i used en-us model its accuracy is little bit .when the slang is american. As i want to recognise indian slang i used En-in model but its acuuracy is 0%. It didn't recognise 1 word out of 100 . I don't know how to increase the accuracy or whether my implementation is corrrect. Please do say me if i want to use it some other way or how to increase its accuracy.

my code

```
package spinxtest;

import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.InputStream;

  import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
  import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
  import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
  import edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone;
  import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Result;
  import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.WordResult;

  public class IndianSlang {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-in/en-in");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-in/cmudict-en-in.dict");
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-in/en-us.lm.bin");
    configuration.setUseGrammar(false);

    LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

    recognizer.startRecognition(true);
   System.out.println("Start speaking. \n");
    SpeechResult result;
     long timer=0;

while (timer < 2*60*1000) {
 result = recognizer.getResult();
 if (result != null)
        {
            System.out.print("You said: ");
            for (WordResult word : result.getWords())
            {
                if (!word.isFiller())
                    System.out.print(word.getWord() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
   else {
            System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
        }
   }
  recognizer.stopRecognition();
   }
   }
```

Jars i use:

```
  WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar
   sphinx4-data-5prealpha-20160628.232535-10.jar
  sphinx4-core-5prealpha-20160628.232526-10.jar
  commons-math3-3.0.jar
  ant-contrib-0.6.jar
  js.jar
  junit-4.8.1.jar
  batch.jar
  jsapi-1.0-base.jar
  tags.jar
```

Comment: You need to provide the sample data to get help on the accuracy. For more details see http://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialtuning

Answer (score -1):

I tried the same and accuracy was not so good because phonemes are different for both models. What you need to do is create compatible dictionary file and language model for your en-in acoustic model. For that install g2p-seq2seq from below link and create your own .dict and .lm.bin files and then try.

[g2p-seq2seq github link](https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq)

Comment: How do you create .lm.bin with g2p-seq2seq ?

Comment: You can follow below link, I prefer using CMUCLMTK.
https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm/